# Cover required for octaginal box

Tags: electrical, gfci

I need to purchase the conversion cover discussed when an octagonal box is used to hold a duplex receptacle. Article stated it was new but could be found online. Please supply e-mail address. Thanks.

Comment: Google "octagon duplex cover" (PS - no clue what you read, but it's not new)

Answer (score 1):

[link to website, not an endorsement as these are available at practically any electrical parts supplier or hardware store.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjE7de8iuDVAhUY0mMKHXTOBIYQjB0IBg&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cesco.com%2FSteel-City-5402-LR-Steel-City-5402-LR--4-in--Steel-Round-and-Octagon-Box-Cover--Flat--Center-Blanked-for-Duplex-Receptacle%2Fp2128636&psig=AFQjCNGTkhABeWZRbJ2Kswhhvto676PYPw&ust=1503121588079051)

[image]